# How can I check if NS String contains a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, scriptable

for an app, i have to search for a function in JavaScript syntax in a NSString.

In java, i've done it this way:

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.Function;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
private Scriptable script;

public boolean bla(String name) {

  Object obj = script.get(name, script);
  if (!(obj instanceof Function)) {
      return false;
  } 

return true;
}
```

Is there an easy way to convert this to objective-c? 
It's in Cocoa touch, so i can't use webkit.

thanks

m0e

Comment: Do you mean, "can I **check** ..." ? Also I don't understand what this has to do with JavaScript.

Comment: oh yes, sry autocorrection ......

Comment: Oh, right, overlooked that. It's [possible to compile JavaScriptCore on iOS](http://www.phoboslab.org/log/2011/06/javascriptcore-project-files-for-ios), so that might be an option. It's relatively heavy-weight, but quite easy to use.

Comment: You could try http://parsekit.com/. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Seems kinda dangerous to say "This looks like a JavaScript functon so I think I'll execute it."  Seems like you should KNOW.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to know if there is a function or do you need to do further processing? Your given example works because the library you are using turns the code into a full-fledged Javascript object and checks for the function. But if you just want a quick and dirty check if the function is there, I would recommend using a substring checking routine (NSString's rangeOfString). Otherwise you are going to have to pull in a whole library from somewhere that parses JavaScript.

Comment: i really need to check if the function is written in javaScript and has the right syntax. Do you know such a library?